# Nested IF statements on a button's onClick

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, onclick

I am working on a custom Visualforce page where I have requirement for a button to function based on a criteria.

This working good:

```
<apex:customButton onclick="{!IF(OR(c.first, c.second), 'doSomething();', 'process();' )}"/>
```

But this is not and is this even valid:

```
<apex:customButton onclick="{!IF(OR(c.first, c.second), 'IF(c.first, 'doSomething1();', 'doSomething2();')', 'process();' )}"/>
```

Comment: You don't need quotation marks around the nested `IF()` function.

Comment: Oh yes, that works now. I thought that was an exception for the `onClick`. I feel the difference now.

Comment: @DavidReed You could post your comment as an Ans, I would love to mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotation marks around the nested `IF()` function. Simply removing them should allow the nested `IF()`s to evaluate cleanly.